# Align chapter and section headings to outer edge

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I am trying to achieve the following result (made with Photoshop):

[image]

I already managed to get the right page formatted correctly, but this does obsiously not work for double sided documents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[includehead,
            top=25mm,
            left=40mm,
            right=35mm
]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\section{This Is a First Level Section} \lipsum[1]
\subsection{And Second Level} \lipsum[2] \pagebreak
\section{First Level Again} \lipsum[3]
\subsection{Second Level} \lipsum[4]    
\end{document}
```

How can i align the headings to the outer edge?

Comment: Such a layout may look more symmetrical but is a pain for the reader. Even in twoside layouts text is read from left to right so you shouldn't force the reader eyes to jump to the right to get the section number, to the middle to read the section title and back again to the left to read the text.

Comment: Thanks, but I would still be interested in a solution for this. Any ideas?

Comment: There is an answer by Markus Kohm on the KOMA-Script website: http://www.komascript.de/node/1976 (German)

Comment: @esdd: The first solution will not give the (probably) expected result for section titles with more than one line.

Comment: @esdd: Thank you very much, I am getting close. Unfortunately the second solution renders the numbers on the wrong side of the page. (Can't try the first one, I am restricted to an older version of the koma scripts.)

Comment: @Ulrike `\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\leavevmode\raggedsection#4}\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip\marginparsep #3}%` for the odd pages?

Comment: @esdd: Something like this. (Interesting way to communicate with Markus can be seen here ;-))

Comment: @sonovice The second solution works for me. Maybe an additional run is needed?

Comment: @esdd: Somehow the absolute page counter of the marginnote package did not get it right. I had to insert an additional `\stepcounter{mn@abspage}` at the beginning of my mainmatter to get it to work properly. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody has asked Markus. There are two suggestions on the KOMA-Script website: [Überschriften am äußeren Rand ausrichten mit Nummer im Rand](http://www.komascript.de/node/1976) (German). Both suggestions needs some runs to get the numbers right.

The first solution needs KOMA-Script version 3.19a or newer. I have changed this code a little so it works now with longer section titles too.

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifthispageodd{\ifthispageodd}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\Ifthispageodd{\raggedleft}{\raggedright}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifthispagewasodd
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\leavevmode\raggedsection#4}\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip\marginparsep #3}%
  \else
    \makebox[0pt][r]{#3\hskip\marginparsep}#4%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\thesubsection\autodot}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\thesubsubsection\autodot}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A section with a long, long, long title that needs more than one line}
\Blindtext
\section{Another section}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

The second example uses package `marginnote` but works also with older KOMA-Script versions.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifthispageodd{\ifthispageodd}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\Ifthispageodd{\raggedleft}{\raggedright}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \marginnote{%
    \usekomafont{disposition}{\usekomafont{section}{%
        \thesection\autodot}}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \marginnote{%
    \usekomafont{disposition}{\usekomafont{subsection}{%
        \thesubsection\autodot}}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
  \marginnote{%
    \usekomafont{disposition}{\usekomafont{subsubsection}{%
        \thesubsubsection\autodot}}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section with a long, long, long title that needs more than one line}
\Blindtext
\section{Another section}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```